# Calculating $\mathbb{E}^2(\sigma_t^2)$ where $\sigma$ is a GARCH(1,1) process

Tags: expected-value, garch, finance, volatility

Given that $\alpha=0,113079$, $\beta = 0,873884$, $\omega = 0,0000081$ (and that $\text{kurtosis}  = 235$), I need to calculate a call price using GARCH volatility:
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265442526_A_Black-Scholes_model_with_GARCH_volatility
[image]

Comment: Could you make a clearer connection between the title and the body of your question? Also, consider moving this to [Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange](https://quant.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I have calculated most of the term from ecuation, but I can't find a formula for the last term in the last row.

I calculated the expected value of a garch volatility as ω/(1-α-β)

Comment: I tried to use the methodolgy from https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265442526_A_Black-Scholes_model_with_GARCH_volatility But I get abnormal negative answers for the CALL and PUT prices nad can't find the problem, so I thought it might have to deal with E^2

Comment: I see. Well, I addressed the question as well as I could, but I am no expert in option pricing.

Comment: Cross posted at Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/63955).

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 2):

I assume $\mathbb{E}(\cdot)$ is the unconditional expectation and suppose $\mathbb{E}^2(\cdot)$ means $[\mathbb{E}(\cdot)]^2$. If so,
$$
[\mathbb{E}(\sigma_t^2)]^2=\left[\frac{\omega}{1-\alpha-\beta}\right]^2.
$$